# Remote Config values didn't reflect

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

Firebase AB Test values reflect only when App install otherwise values never changed , Is there anything missing in code or from firebase console .
Anyone have an idea what will the possible cause of this issue ?

Comment: Assuming you are using RemoteConfig, are you sure you overwrite default caching that is set to 12 hours? https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#throttling

Comment: yeh i set 0 for minimum fetch time

Comment: Then could you elaborate more on what are you are trying to achieve? It's best when you have some example how it works and how you would like it to work